# How to fix java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException in android

Tags: android

```
public static boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
        boolean isValid = false;

        String expression = "^[\\w\\.-]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            isValid = true;
        }
        return isValid;
    }
```

I am calling this in Activity for email validation

```
  if (!Util.isEmailValid(binding.etEmail.getText().toString().trim())) {
                Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.valid_email), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
```

i am getting the crash report .

java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Error in {min,max} interval near index 7
(+\d{٣}[\s-]?\d{0}[\s-]?)

let me know if not clear i will post full crash report

Please help me what i am doing wrong and how to fix this crash .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+"
```

instead of this

```
String emailPattern = "^[\\w\\.-]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$"
```

Comment: Thanks for help me ,but will it cover for all validation which is given in question ?

Comment: Yup. Most of them. Why don't you test them out? Thank you.

Comment: Thanks its working but can you please help me to understand why this crash is coming this  crash is not coming for all device its coming for specific device like Android OS-10